# Center Animated Object in iPad Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, ipad, animation, safari

I am trying to make my website [http://www.TheTapReport.com](http://www.thetapreport.com) lower bottom scroll animation "arrow" display center on an iPad Safari Browser instead of left justified. The text "scroll" and the mouse objects appear to be centered, however, the arrow is not. I have tested this animation on most browsers and all appears to be always centered except for with the iPad.

```
#scrolldown {
bottom: 40px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: -50px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
z-index: 100;
}
#scrolldown p {
font: 700 0.7em/1em 'Avenir',sans-serif;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: scroll;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: scroll;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-name: scroll;
-o-animation-name: scroll;
-o-animation-duration: 2s;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }

#scrolldown > p {
font: 700 0.7em/1em 'Avenir',sans-serif;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-name: scroll;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: scroll;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-name: scroll;
-o-animation-name: scroll;
-o-animation-duration: 2s;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.mouse {
border: 2px solid #000;
border-radius: 13px;
display: block;
height: 46px;
left: 50%;
margin: 10px 0 0 -13px;
position: fixed;
width: 26px;
}

.mouse {
border: 2px solid #7C7D7F;
border-radius: 13px;
display: block;
height: 46px;
left: 50%;
margin: 10px 0 0 -13px;
position: fixed;
width: 26px;
}
.mouse span {
display: block;
font-size: 1 em;
margin: 6px auto;  
 }
 @-moz-keyframes scroll {
0% {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(5px);
}
}

@-o-keyframes scroll {
0% {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
 }
 100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(5px);
 }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes scroll {
 0% {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
 }
 100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(5px);
}
}
@keyframes scroll {
0% {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(5px);
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using normalize.css and or modernizr?

Comment: I never heard of them until now. I looked each one up but don't fully understand how they will center the arrow. Can you please elaborate how to utilize one of these options to center the arrow? Thank you

Comment: The reason I suggested modernizr and normalize.css is because your issue seems to be affecting one browser differently than the others. These tools help web developers force multiple browsers to behave in the same exact manner. So browser inconsistencies shouldn't be a problem when using them. http://modernizr.com/. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/. Follow instructions on website, it shouldn't be a huge effort because you are just inserting a pre-built code into your pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will give them a try. Thank you!